# Unicode checkmarks

Tags: html, unicode, ascii, html-entities

I'm trying to find a checkmark symbol that will work across operating systems and browsers.  So far, I have these two:

```
Version 1: ✓ Version 2: ✔
```

([source](http://jsbin.com/acixil/5))

But they only work in most browsers in OS X.  Is there an equivalent out there that I can reliably use?

In other words, what else can I use besides these:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick_(check_mark)
(shows up in OS X and not Windows XP)

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me and I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

✓+ Although, gifs, pngs, jpgs are cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, use an image. If you're using characters you always need to rely on fonts being present on the client system which may or may not be there. As you noted, XP has horrible Unicode coverage by default and even WOFF will only help you with current browsers. If you have that many users on XP there probably are still those who use IE 6.